# I've had some bad questions in the past, a warning says to edit them, but how should I?

Tags: support, edits, post-ban, question-quality

> "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of   being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity."

I want to edit my previous questions but usually someone makes an edit suggestion, and I'm not sure if I have to approve it or they get automatically edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> usually someone makes an edit suggestion, and i'm not sure if i have to approve it or they get automatically edited.

Suggested edits go into a review queue that higher rep users can see and either approve or reject. This may happen before you get a chance to do so yourself, though it is better if you do it yourself given the chance (after all, it is your post).

The help centre also contains articles about how to write [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), so if you do edit - make sure to follow these guidelines.